# how to provide permission(create/view) to group in gcp and enable logging for the same

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, permissions, audit, google-iam

**How to provide permissions ->**

- How organization admin delegate create/view permission(identity
  access management) or access to group in google cloud platform ?? and
  enable logging for the same??
- Can we create alias and grant permission to it as well??

Not able to find relevant documents to explain the steps to follow. Can anyone please enlighten?  I am new to Google platform.

Went through following links which does not speak about groups permissions precisely.

- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference

To understand audit logging , went through following links

- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging

Can anybody share some link or pointer for my understanding.

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

Google Cloud offers Identity and Access Management (IAM), which lets you give more granular access to specific Google Cloud resources and prevents unwanted access to other resources. IAM lets you adopt the security principle of least privilege, so you grant only the necessary access to your resources.

IAM lets you control who (users) has what access (roles) to which resources by setting IAM policies. IAM policies grant specific role(s) to a user giving the user certain permissions.

If you want more information about IAM follow [this link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org)

More information about Loggin in [Google IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging)